# SSH Remote access in Aptana

Tags: ssh, aptana, remote-access, putty, filezilla

I have since connected to my SSH site using Putty and Filezilla.  Putty and Filezilla give me direct access to the appropriate directories and Filezilla gives me a full path from the top level directory.  I have then tried the same path from the starting point in Aptana, but get blocked one level above my target directory.  If I collapse all the directories in Putty and Filezilla and try to expand again, Putty works fine, but Filezilla then blocs at the same point as Aptana.  So there is some subtle difference in approach between Filezilla and Aptana and Putty.

I was looking for a way to get an encryted link when editing files on my hosted webserver when using Aptana Studio.  I can get an ordinary Remote FTP link set up and use that to edit files.  The SSH facility looked as though it could do a secure link, so got the SSH details off my ISP and set up in Studio.  In the setup I was asked to select a directory, but the ones available were all system directories rather than my htdocs tree.  However by leaving out the default provided /, I could get to the htdocs tree and see all  my files under remote.  However when I try to load a file to Studio, I get a file does not exist message.

I'm new to SSH (and Studio) and don't know whether what I am trying to do is not possible or there is something else I need to set up.  So far I have  just been using Studio as a remote editor for PHP and HTML.  I suspect there is a much better and professional way to set up what I am doing under Studio (even ignoring the secure transfer) as I am currently doing separate backup of the files in Filezilla, but just haven't figured out the way to set everything up yet.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I'd like to post this as a comment to your question, but I'm pretty new here, so the system doesn't allow me to.

Anyway. You can add connections to remote servers over ssh like this:

1. If you don't have the remote tab go to Window -> Show View -> Remote
2. Rightclick in the remote tab and click "Add New FTP Site..."
3. Change the Protocol to SFTP and put in your credentials (you can use Username/Password or Username/Private Key authentification)

When you close Aptana with files still opened, it usually show you those files when you reopen Aptana later. It seams not to do this when you work with files of a SFTP remote host and shows you an error instead. I guess this is because it tries to validate those files (if they still exists) but doesn't authenticate with the remote host first. So nothing to worry there.

Hope this helps.